# Wordpress Shortcode Output Buffering Renders Content When Saving Post in WP Admin

Tags: wordpress, buffer, shortcode

I have a WP shortcode that is giving me problems.

Basically, the shortcode just pulls content from another post using a couple of parameters. It then loads up a partial template.

The problem occurs in WP Admin when saving the page that contains the shortcode. When saving the page updates do in fact save correctly but the resulting page is a page that outputs the contents of the shortcode.

I'm using output buffering around get_template_part() for two reasons: 1. So I only have one instance of the template in my code - and - 2. Because the template is actually pretty substantial and appending all of it to an output variable would be a daunting task.

The shortcode works fine in every way except when saving the page.

**Here is a video demonstrating the issue:**

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1146323?key=103ae00d841b47cee8a902eb18c8988a

**Here is my code:**

```html
function get_main_page_content( $atts ) {   
    
    $main_page_id = $atts['main_page_id'];
    $section = $atts['section'];
    $people_display_option = $atts['people_display_option'];
    $GLOBALS['sc_display_option'] = $people_display_option;
    
    ob_start();
    
    if(have_rows('flexible_content', $main_page_id)):
        while(have_rows('flexible_content', $main_page_id)): the_row();
        
            if ( $section == 'agenda' ) {

                get_template_part('partials/agenda');
                
            }
            
            if ( $section == 'people_cards' ) {
                    
                get_template_part('partials/people-cards');
                
            }
            
        endwhile;
    endif;
    
    ob_end_flush();
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    return $output;
    
    
}
add_shortcode('get_main_page_content', 'get_main_page_content');
```

Comment: I can't run your script at the moment, but it looks to me like ob_end_flush() is not needed and is redundant. That might be causing the OB to send twice, resulting in that code on your screen. I'd be curious if your problem persists if you drop that line. Also, for a very simplified version of your exact usecase, check this blog post: https://konstantin.blog/2013/get_template_part-within-shortcodes/

Comment: Ah man, @GregBurkett! You done saved me hours of converting this output into a string. Thank God you know more about output buffering than I do. If you copy this to the answer, I'll be sure to give you credit. Thanks the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like `ob_end_flush()` is not needed and is redundant. That might be causing the OB to send twice, resulting in that code on your screen.

I'd be curious if your problem persists if you drop that line. Also, for a very simplified version of your exact usecase, check this blog post:

https://konstantin.blog/2013/get_template_part-within-shortcodes